# Can arguments be passed to List variable in ROBOT framework

Tags: robotframework

My problem is:

I am trying something like this
`${${variable}}`    Create List

`${variable}` --this will be passed as an argument.

I get the following error when I do it:-
No keyword with name `'${${variable}}'` found

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks for giving a thought.I was trying to read a CSV and create separate lists for each element of first line.Then add the subsequententries(from line 2 to lastline) from CSV to the created lists(from first line of CSV).I got it working after some research.Thanks again...Malay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a list use @{list}, but not ${variable}. To parse ${variable} to list, use something like this: @{list} ${first_variable} {seconn_variable}.

More info you can get here:
http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.7.4#list-variables

Hope this would help you!